# When the expected value of the gradient of function is equal to the expected value of the function multiplied by the gradient itself?

Tags: expected-value, gradient

I'm having doubts on the conditions of an equality. Considering $f(X,w): \mathbb{R}^n \xrightarrow{} \mathbb{R}^n$ a function of n-variate random variable $X$ with an unknown distribution $p(x)$ and $w$ parameters in $m$ dimensions. I have:

$$
  E_{X}[f(X,w)\nabla_{w} f(X,w)] = aE_{X}[\nabla_{w} f(X,w)]
$$
When is this true? I arrived to condition $E_{X}[f(X,w)] = a$ with the following steps:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{E_{X}[f(X,w)\nabla_{w} f(X,w)]}{E_{X}[\nabla_{w} f(X,w)]} &= a \\
E_{X}[\frac{f(X,w)\nabla_{w} f(X,w)}{\nabla_{w} f(X,w)}] &= a \\
E_{X}[f(X,w)] &= a
\end{align}
$$
But I believe that the second step is wrong and so this condition, that could be true only in specific cases. Anyway, there exists a condition in terms of $E_{X}[f(X,w)] ?$

Comment: Suppose $f(X,w)=w^2$ for all $X$ and $w,$ whence the gradient w.r.t. $w$ is $2w.$ Are you prepared to conclude $2w^3=E[(w^2)(2w)]=E[2w]=2w$ for all $w$??

Comment: @whuber actually the first equation is what I have. I need to find the conditions on when that is true, not when is not true. For example I can see that $E_{X}[\nabla f(X,w)(f(X,w) - a)] = 0$ . But I'm not able to say more on $E_{X}[f(X,w)]$

Comment: Please state that in your question, because that's not what either your title or the text currently say.  In the meantime, notice that any $f$ that does not depend on $w$ will satisfy your initial equation -- but that implies almost nothing about the expectation of $f(X,w),$ which could be any real number.

Comment: You're totally right, I'm sorry. I'll correct the title and the text.

Comment: Ok, in the case $f$ doesn't depend on $w$. But there exist any other conditions in terms of $E_{X}[f(X,w)]$ that keep that equation true? Thank you in advance

Comment: Re "doesn't depend on:" not so.  I only offered that as a simple example.  It's only the case that the *expectations* don't depend on $w.$  For instance, let $X$ have a Normal$(0,1)$ distribution and define $f(X,w)=wX.$

Comment: Ok, you just gave me an important hint! Thank you!